# Spring security passes complete decoded jwt token to loadUserByUsername method how can I get it to pass only username from the token instead?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've encoded additional data to jwt token like user authorities,username etc. Spring security is invoking loadUserByUsername with complete jwt token decoded how can I get it to pass only username from the token to userdetailsService?

code

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider).userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new PlainTextPasswordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);//NOSONAR
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint(messageSource);
    }

}
```

UserDetailsService

```
@Service("myUserDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${jwt.password.secret}")
    public String password;

    @Autowired
    AekAztabRepository aekAztabRepository;

    @Autowired
    ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Aektab> aekAztab = aektabRepository.findByGeNr(username);
          if(aektab.isPresent()) {
              if (aekAztab.get().getGeNr().equals(username)) {
                  return conversionService.convert(aektab.get(), User.class);
              }
          }
          else{
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user name");
          }

        return null;
    }

    public List<UserDetails> populateUserDetails()
    {

        List<UserDetails> userDetails =new ArrayList<>();

        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

the username that is passed to loadUserByUsername is username=`{"username":"123456788","language":null,"deactivationReason":null,"terminationYear":null,"authorities":[{"authority":"ROLE_ADMIN_ROK"}],"active":false,"terminated":false}`

how can I override security configurations to get spring security to pass only username from this token ? And which one is called first AuthenticationProvider or UserdetailsService?

update
AuthenticationProvider

```
 @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();



            // use the credentials
            // and authenticate against the third-party system
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement your own AuthenticationManager which constructs your desired final concrete implementation of Authentication object for example UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken or whatever is your exact need. AuthenticationManager delegates to AuthenticationProvider which calls your UserDetailService.

Comment: I've implemented AuthenticationManager which is not getting invoked,I'll provide the code

Comment: Your current code uses default implementation of AuthenticationManager, you need to remove that part and define your own custom bean for your custom implementation, else it gets overridden by Spring Security-s default config. Edit: You need new `AuthenticationManager` not `AuthenticationProvider` . Same contract, different purpose.

Comment: You don't need your own `AuthenticationManager` but indeed either an `AuthenticationProvider` or even better let your filter construct what you need. So either change your `AuthenticationProvider` implementation to extract that information from the passed in `Authentication` or do this in the filter.